# Xamarin Android Web Service over HTTPS

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin, https

I'm having some difficulties consuming a web service that is available only over https.

I have read posts from several other people who is having issues with achieving this as well, but none of the answers I have seen so far has fixed the problem for me, so I will try to explain my issue here and hope some of you know how to get past this obstacle.

I'm using Xamarin Studio 6.1.1 developing for Android specifically.
I have set the "HttpClient Implementation" under "Android Build" for the project to "AndroidClientHandler" (which appears to be the latest implementation and should support TLS 1.2).

I have added a web reference (not as WCF) to the web service and supplied the login information when prompted... So far everything is going as expected.

Note: I have tested the web service from a console application in Visual Studio and it works as expected.

However, when I attempt to call one of the methods of the web service I get the same error that I can see so many others have encountered before me which is this "Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)".

I have tried several of the previous posted solutions but nothing seems to help.

1.A) providing the callback function for ServicePointManager:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateValidationCallBack;
```

1.B) the callback function:

```
private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
     object sender,
     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
     System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
        if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
        if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
        {
            if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
            {
                foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                       (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                    {
                        // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                        {
                            // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                            // so the method returns false.
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
            // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
            // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // In all other cases, return false.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

2) Creating an instance of the AesCryptoServiceProvider:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider b = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider();
```

If anyone can has a solution this the apparently pretty common problem, please don't hesitate to let me know, I only have so much hair...

kind regards,
Aidal

Answer (score 1):

Possible known bug. Search this here for "https": https://releases.xamarin.com

> [Mono], [Xamarin.iOS], [Xamarin.Android], [Xamarin.Mac] – 43566 –
>   “TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) … Invalid
>   certificate received from server.” with “Error code: 0x5” or “Error
>   code: 0xffffffff800b010f” when attempting to access HTTPS servers on
>   ports other than 443

Bug reference: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44708

Comment: Aha! So this is actually a bug in the current version, which means I'm not gonna be able to get this to work regardless of what I do. In that case I suppose my only option is the wait for a fix?

Comment: Well, what port number are you using? 443 should be fine. Also, returning just `true` from the certification validation callback should help as a workaround but *is not an option for any productive app*.

Comment: The port is not 443 and I cannot request a change to this unfortunately. I have already tried the workaround you mention and it doesn't work. I have serialised a few responses from the service in question and I'm working with those in my app while hoping the issue will be resolved soon. Thanks for leading my attention to the known issues on the release page.